# Is there a changelog for Ubuntu Security Notices?

Tags: security, canonical, changelog

While keeping track of [USNs](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) for the Stack Clash vulnerability, I noticed that already published USNs were showing up before ones published later. USNs 33{24..27}-1 were originally published on the 19th, and now they show a date of 21st (compare [the webpage](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3324-1/) with [the mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2017-June/003901.html) for 3324-1). For 3324-1, it seems some kernel packages were dropped from the list. However, it is tedious to examine all the updated USNs manually.

Is there a place where I can see what changed in a USN?

---

Aside: why would they update an USN, instead of posting a new one and incrementing the number after the hyphen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no changelogs of updates to the USNs themselves. Usually, once published, the USNs do not change, other than to fix a typo or make a slight wording change.

For the set of kernel USNs that covered the Stack Clash issue ([CVE-2017-1000364](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-1000364.html)), mistakes were made in the publication process that included references and descriptions to fixes that were not actually included in the kernels published to the -security pockets. They covered issues that were pending for the next round of regular [Stable Release Update cadence kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/StableReleaseCadence). Due to this, the USNs were updated to include only the CVE-2017-1000364 reference and description.

These issues will be addressed in the next round of kernel updates, which were [planned](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-sru-announce/2017-June/000097.html) to be released already, but were [delayed](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-sru-announce/2017-June/000099.html) due to the need to incorporate the fixes for CVE-2017-1000364, as well as to address [regressions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772) introduced by the Stack Clash fixes.

Comment: Are mailing list users expected to check the website as well? The list haven't received the updated USNs.